# Blazor - How to execute the form submit in Button click using ICommand

Tags: blazor, icommand

How to execute the form submit in Button click using ICommand

How to pass parameter in ICommand execute

```
@using System.Windows.Input

<button @onclick="buttonClick"> Blazor Button</button>

@code {

    private ICommand _command;
    public ICommand Command
    {
        get => _command;
        set => _command = value;
    }

    private void buttonClick()
    {
        this.Command?.Execute(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to trigger the form submit from an ICommand? Wouldn't it be much easier to just make a normal `<button type="submit">` and then set the `OnValidSubmit` of the form you want to submit?

Comment: My requirement how to pass parameter in ICommand.exceute.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible to do as `System.Windows.Input` (e.g. ICommand) is for WPF not Blazor.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only option to handle a click event on a button is the OnClick event, which is an EventCallback binding. It would be nice if a binding was available for a command of type ICommand as well. Blazor

Comment: I haven't done much with WPF (where ICommand is mainly used as far as I'm aware), but from what I can remember the reason you pass ICommand is indeed because you want to bind the command to an event. In Blazor, you simply don't need to do that. The buttonClick method is already what you would consider the ICommand in WPF. Now if you want to pass one (or multiple) parameters into that method, you can use `@onclick=@(()=>buttonClick(parameter))`.

Comment: @Nijenhof Having the ICommand with execute, canExecute and Executing is usefull even in Blazor if you use viewmodels and you need to show the user the button has been clicked and work is being done, or disabling it. Without it you have to make a bunch of variables and bind them all togheter.

Comment: I believe ICommand can be used outside WPF.  It appears Microsoft moved it out of WPF DLLs into more foundational DLLs (System.ObjectModel.dll), and it is even in netstandard2.0.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.icommand?view=netstandard-2.0

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i got an answer Please refer to below link.

https://github.com/virzak/blazor-wasm/commit/6b15c5f5dc61e333c3dbfec41fd09dd40cd5302f

```
<button @onclick="@(() => Model.DecrementCommand.Execute(true))"> Blazor Button</button>
```

> ```
> @code {
>
>     CommandModel Model = new CommandModel();
> }
>
> public class CommandModel
>     {
>         public ICommand DecrementCommand;
>         public int age = 30;
>         public CommandModel()
>         {
>             DecrementCommand = new RelayCommand<bool>(DecrementExecute);
>         }
>
>         public void DecrementExecute(bool decrement)
>         {
>             if (decrement)
>             {
>                 age -= 1;
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 age += 1;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

Comment: This lambda simply begs to be extracted to a separate method.

Comment: So it is possible. You get none of the benfits and all the drawbacks of an ICommand.

Comment: And what are those benefits and drawbacks?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at blazorise and reactiveui.blazor.

Blazise buttons support icommand.